# How do i make multiple screens on flutter - more than 2 screens

Tags: flutter

i am needing some help please. I have googled this and I keep getting to the same result of making 2 screens. 
 I'm trying to make multiple screens on flutter. 
 I have found another answer on this forum but it didn't seem to work for me, i kept getting errors in the code. I'll include basic code that works for 2 screens down below.

I'm actually still learning flutter and trying to make a prototype to show a client. I tried using wireframes but all i managed to find was a place to draw out the app, i want a live skeleton app i can show the customer with pages. 
**What I'm doing?** I'm trying to make more than 2 routes, name each route, navigate back to the home screen.
**What I've tried?** I will include code below
**What is my result?** I'm able to navigate 2 screens (routes) perfectly fine
**Expected result?** I'm wanting more than 2, i'm needing at least about 6 routes

Code that works

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext ctxt) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new FirstScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class FirstScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext ctxt) {
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text("Multi Page Application"),
        ),
        body: new Checkbox(
            value: false,
            onChanged: (bool newValue) {
              Navigator.push(
                ctxt,
                new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (ctxt) => new SecondScreen()),
              );
            }));
  }
}

class SecondScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext ctxt) {
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text("Multi Page Application Page - 1"),
        ),
        body: new Checkbox(
            value: false,
            onChanged: (bool newValue) {
              //this pushes forward to screen 1
              Navigator.push(ctxt,
                  new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (ctxt) => new FirstScreen()));
              //    Navigator.pop(ctxt) ; // Pop from stack back to screen 1
            }));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i found out how to do this after a lot of playing around in the editor. All i did was i made a third screen called third_screen.dart then i put the code `Navigator.push(ctxt, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (ctxt) => new ThirdScreen()));`

then on the third screen i copied the code above directly and just changed to "class ThirdScreen extends StatelessWidget " into the second screen

then on the third screen i put the command to go back to previous page

```
 Navigator.pop(context);
```

This takes me back to the previous screen i was on.

so full code is

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext ctxt) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new FirstScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class FirstScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext ctxt) {
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text("Multi Page Application"),
        ),
        body: new Checkbox(
            value: false,
            onChanged: (bool newValue) {
              Navigator.push(
                ctxt,
                new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (ctxt) => new SecondScreen()),
              );
            }));
  }
}

class SecondScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext ctxt) {
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text("Multi Page Application Page - 1"),
        ),
        body: new Checkbox(
            value: false,
            onChanged: (bool newValue) {
              //this pushes forward to screen 3
              Navigator.push(ctxt,
                  new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (ctxt) => new ThirdScreen()));
             
            }));
  }
}
class ThirdScreen extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext ctxt) {
        return new Scaffold(
            appBar: new AppBar(
              title: new Text("Multi Page Application Page - 1"),
            ),
            body: new Checkbox(
                value: false,
                onChanged: (bool newValue) {
              
                  Navigator.pop(ctxt) ; // Pop from stack back to screen 1
                }));
      }
    }
```